# kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js Tango sample doesnt clear canvas properly Android 4.1.2

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-shape-tango-with-kineticjs/

works on any web browser,
Android 4.1.2 - doesn't clear canvas properly

Comment: You should give [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read. Links to your full code are good for answerers to get additional information, but you should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you have any additional about the issue that can help potential answerers?

Comment: honey, its all there

Comment: From the help center entry I linked to: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to then do so - but **also include the code in your question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." (My emphasis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andoid canvas is buggy.
Look there: http://slash-system.com/en/how-to-fix-android-html5-canvas-issues/ ( or https://github.com/lavrton/kineticjs-tips-and-tools#ghost-shapes)

Comment: got all works around but non of it help but thanks for effort anyway (for some reason the first hit never clear canvas after that it works good when I added delay.)